# How JMS AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE mode can have duplicate messages

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I am creating a JMS topic client with spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer. Below is a sample code

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setDestinationName("topic.monitor");
        container.setPubSubDomain(true);
        container.setCacheLevel(3);
        container.setRecoveryInterval(2000);
        container.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        container.setMessageListener(...)
```

As far as I can understand that there is no way that client can receive duplicate messages in "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" mode(although message can be lost). But I am receiving the duplicate messages randomly. I wonder how it can happen? Is the onMessage method thread-safe?

Can anyone can give some hints where can be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There is no deviation from the JMS behaviour that in "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" mode, only one messages get received on client.
Problem was that there were two instances of "DefaultMessageListenerContainer" that gets invoked at certain moment of time and then there were two messages that starts arriving.